# Remove colones filters in excel document using OLE

Tags: c++, excel, ole

My program is in c++, it is functional using microsoft OLE with Excel.

I was wondering if there were are any procedure call or somethings to remove all colones filters.

**Explanations:**

```
.    A      B     ...
1   IDs   Value   ...
2    0      25    ...
3    1      32    ...
...  ...    ...
```

Id and Value have little dropdown boxes. Clicking on those dropdown boxes i can select a value, and the rows displayed below will only be the ones containing this specific value, hiding the others.

So sometimes when I open a file I something like this:

```
.    A      B     ...
1   IDs   Value   ...
2    0      25    ... //Betwin this line and the line above there are 6 hidden rows.
8    6      15    ...
...  ...    ...
```

How to disable those filters from OLE, in oder to always have all entries displayed.

And if it's not possible, is there any property to know if a given cell/range/row is displayed or hidden?

I am doing an range extraction from fileA and then insert it into fileB, but when the line is hidden in fileA I get an error.

Comment: What are "colones filters"?

Comment: Yep, let me edit the question

Comment: @Gabe Sorry, I got overhelmed by my problem and forgot to specify it clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want [`Worksheet.ShowAllData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197246.aspx). The docs say:

> Makes all rows of the currently filtered list visible. If AutoFilter is in use, this method changes the arrows to "All."

I don't know what a "colones filter" is, but I'm assuming it's an "AutoFilter".

Comment: I'll give it a try and tell you if it's work. Thanks

Comment: Do you know if this method have to be called over the excel oject or over a worksheet? workbook? I tried this but I got an exception: `_worksheet.OleProcedure("ShowAllData");`

Comment: Ok got the solution, you have to check before using showalldata, if any filter is activated.